# Bootstrap tagsinput Add item issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

So, i started today using this bootstrap-tagsinput, first thing i tryied was adding a new tag dinamically, i spent now about an hour to do this simple task and i still have the same problem.
Heres the code i'm using:

```
$("#test").tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: true,
    itemValue: function(item) { return item._id; },
    itemText: function(item) { return item.name; }
});

$("#test").tagsinput('add', {_id: 1, name: 'Testing'});
```

The result i get is: **Uncaught Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set**
but as you can see i do set itemValue. I also put the code in a [JSFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/7fp5hh2j/2/) to be easy for you to test. I noticed not only itemValue is not being set but none of my options, because i also can't duplicate tags (but i allow it on options).

Anybody know what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

First of all:

> Just add data-role="tagsinput" to your input field to automatically change it to a tags input field.

I've just taken the text above from the [this site](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

So, if you are using that attribute (I saw it in your fiddle), you shouldn't do it again on javascript later.

Besides that, the `itemValue` and `itemText` properties, you should pass only the name of the property that the component will look inside the item.

```
$("#test").tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: true,
    itemValue: '_id',
    itemText: 'name'
});

$("#test").tagsinput('add', {_id: 1, name: 'Testing'});
```

Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7fp5hh2j/3/

Comment: Erasing data-role="tagsinput" i'll only be able to change the tags dinamically, i need both dinamically and manually(typing the new tag)

Comment: Do you need that _id? Because I think that the only way of achieving what you want is to use the data-role attribute, and then adding directly but without the _id.

Comment: Yes, i have a MongoDB model that has a friendly name( that will be shown to the user) but i'll need it's id to do all actions to it.